# FSA Rollover Funds - Leaving Company

Tags: united-states, rollover, fsa

I had $600 left over in my WageWorks Health Care FSA at the end of 2016. I am not contributing anything in 2017. WageWorks tells me that $500 will roll over after the window to submit 2016 claims ends, some time in April. Problem is, I am leaving the company at the beginning of March (by choice). I have the following questions since WageWorks was unable to answer them:

- Will the roll over of these funds be cancelled upon my resignation or will they still roll over and wait to collect these funds at the end of the year?
- Will (or should) I be able to retroactively submit claims for expenses occurred during the period where my funds had not yet rolled over but was still employed (Jan-Mar)?

Comment: You said that WageWorks was unable to answer these questions.  Did they tell you to ask your employer?

Comment: I will not be telling my company for a few more weeks, so I cannot quite ask yet.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, these things often come down to company policy, so I don't think anyone here will be able to definitively answer this for you.  Employers are not even required to allow the FSA $500 rollover.

If you are planning on leaving your employer, I recommend you find a use for that money and file the claim before you leave.  You can use it on any medical expense listed in [Publication 502](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-publication-502), including dental work, eyeglasses/contact lenses, chiropractic care, bandages, and other items not covered by your insurance.

Certainly any expense that happens after your last day is not covered, due to the [nature of the FSA](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/74999/10997).  But since you are thinking about it now, it shouldn't matter whether or not they will accept claims from you after your gone; just make sure that you file a claim for your medical expenses before the last day arrives.  If, for some reason, you are unable to file the claim before your last day, you could still try filing the claim afterward.  The worst that can happen is they deny it.