# Could my FSA from my previous job disqualify me from doing an HSA with my new one?

Tags: united-states, hsa, fsa

I had my previous job 2015 through August 2018. Near the start of the job, I remember contributing something like $200 to an FSA. I regretted my decision (since I hate dealing with FSA complications) and didn't contribute further. I think that $200 may have carried over through the years being under the $500 limit but I'm not sure. I basically forgot about it having not used any health care and am not sure I have any way of logging back into it.

I started my new job October 2018. I'd like to enroll in the high deductible plan with an HSA, but I'm wondering if this FSA could in any way disqualify me in my new job. I think it's not possible, but I read various pages mentioning grace periods for FSAs, and I'd just like to confirm for sure that I'm qualified to open an HSA.

Comment: You were enrolled in the FSA in 2015 but never re-enrolled?  You need to have a positive FSA enrollment, and some contribution, for any sort of carryover.  If you didn't re-enroll in 2016, 2017, and 2018 you wouldn't have an FSA after 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FSA is an employer plan with a feature called [use-it-or-lose-it](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/74999/10997). It ends when your employment ends, and any money remaining in the plan is forfeited. If you left your old employer in August 2018, you certainly aren’t covered by the FSA now. It will not prevent you from being HSA-eligible.

Comment: Also, new job, new insurance plan.  HSA requires a HDHP.  https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p969.pdf is the real answer.  If you have an HSA you can also have a limited FSA.  See page 4, Other Coverage and Other Employee Plans.